# How to multiply 2 functions with conditions

Tags: functions, conditional-probability

$$f(y|x)= 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{x},& \text{if } 0\leq y \leq x\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

$$f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    2x,& \text{if } 0\leq x \leq 1\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I need to find $f(x,y)$ but I don’t know how to multiply the conditional function $f(y|x)*f(x) = f(x,y)$

Comment: How do I write them it’s difficult please don’t downgrade

Comment: Why do you denote $f$ both functions??? Your problem is not clear.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is incomprehensible. You will need to explain it better if you want an answer.

Comment: How do I multiply $f(y|x)*f(x)$ there are conditions what’s the rules

Comment: The author did this $ f(x,y)= 2x * \frac{1}{x}=2$

Comment: But it’s not trivial to multiply like that I am not sure how to multiply 2 case functions .

Comment: The question taken from probability course it’s the conditional probability function multiplied by the probability function of random variable x .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can observe, is that if not $0\le y\le x\le 1$, then one of the two functions will be zero. So we have:
$$
f(y|x)\cdot f(x) = \begin{cases}
2 & 0\le y \le x \le 1 \\
0 & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
The domain is the triangle bounded by the lines $y=0$, $x=1$ and $y=x$. To be very explicit:
$$
f(y|x)\cdot f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac1x \cdot 2x & y\in[0,x] \wedge x\in[0,1] \\
0 \cdot 2x & y\notin[0,x] \wedge x\in[0,1] \\
\frac1x \cdot 0 & y\in[0,x] \wedge x\notin[0,1] \\
0\cdot0 & y\notin[0,x] \wedge x\notin[0,1] \\
\end{cases}
$$
Makes sense?

Comment: Yes thank you very much sir .